# Can you export data from PnP PowerShell into Excel?

Tags: pnp-powershell, csv

I'm exporting data from PnP PowerShell to a csv file:

```
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Users\wxmuldom\Documents\Data\TELLDocuments.csv"
```

There doesn't seem to be any way that I can control the order of the columns.  Is there a way to control the column order?  Is it possible to export to an Excel Template?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details of what you are trying achieve and why PowerShell why not just export from the list directly?

Answer (score 1):

Do a select with the desired columns and order and pipe that to Export-CSV. Exmaple

```
Get-Process | select WorkingSet64, ProcessName | Export-Csv c:\testfolder\test.csv
```

i.e.

```
your-PNPcmdlet | select yourColumns | Export-Csv filename and options
```

While there is no direct output to Excel, PowerShell can create an Excel object and write to it using the Excel API. Do a web search for "PowerShell create Excel file" for examples.